# Replace column values with NaN if the value on the column next to it is not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace some strings in a column with NaN but only if the string on the column next to it (same row) is not NaN. (Python)

My columns look like this:

```
FOLDER       FILE

nan          03.jpg
services     services
services     services
nan          20190129_145625.jpg
nan          20190129_145627.jpg
```

So, I want to remove `services` from the column on the right because is already on the column on the left. I dont want to do it by saying replace with NaN all strings that are no `.jpg` because I have other strings I'm not showing here that are not `jpg`.

Thanks

Comment: What are your column names? You should look up using .loc with .isna() in pandas

Comment: @EmiOB The names are FOLDER & FILE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
df.loc[~df['FOLDER'].isna(), 'FILE'] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
     FOLDER                 FILE
0       NaN               03.jpg
1  services                  NaN
2  services                  NaN
3       NaN  20190129_145625.jpg
4       NaN  20190129_145627.jpg
```